# TF message visible in "rostopic echo /tf" but not in Rviz and tf_monitor

Tags: rosjava, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are using our own implementation to publish a tfMessage type through rosjava.

In the simplest test I can see the message with the command `rostopic echo /tf` as:

```
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 567527
      stamp: 
        secs: 567
        nsecs: 526999929
      frame_id: map
    child_frame_id: robot
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
      rotation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
        w: 1.0
```

While this looks fine, the command `rosrun tf tf_monitor` shows no frames, `rosrun tf tf_echo map robot` is unable to return the transform (empty list of current frames), and rviz does not find any frames.

The command `rosrun tf view_frames` generates [this visualization](http://cl.ly/image/08443o3G0G2J).

The data is coming from a simulator where I publish the /tf message and the /clock. The tf message time stamp equals the current simulation time in /clock. The parameter `use_sim_time` is set to true.

Interestingly, recording and playing a rosbag with the topics /tf and /clock works, and the /tf transformation shows up correctly in tf_monitor and rviz.

My setup is ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

Does anybody has an idea on how to debug this behaviour to figure out what's going wrong? Any suggestions welcome. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190337/tf-message-visible-in-%22rostopic-echo-/tf%22-but-not-in-rviz-and-tf_monitor/) by [Péter Fankhauser](https://answers.ros.org/users/20024/p%C3%A9ter-fankhauser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-08-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-15**:
can you share you frame.pdf from `rosrun tf view_frames`

**Comment by [Péter Fankhauser](https://answers.ros.org/users/20024/p%C3%A9ter-fankhauser/) on 2014-08-15**:
I have added the view_frames visualization: http://cl.ly/image/08443o3G0G2J

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-16**:
I see some problem with timestamp, you can see tf is 74.913 seconds old while you are publishing 1000hz.

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2017-07-05**:
related/same: http://answers.ros.org/question/265441/tf_echo-is-correct-yet-no-result-from-lookuptranform/

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2017-07-05**:
related/same: http://answers.ros.org/question/231914/tf_echo-can-find-transform-but-waitfortransform-cant/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message type for the /tf topic changed when the backend was switched to tf2 in Hydro.

Are you publishing a `tf2_msgs/TFMessage` or the older `tf/tfMessage` ?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Péter Fankhauser](https://answers.ros.org/users/20024/p%C3%A9ter-fankhauser/) on 2014-08-19**:
This was it, thank you for the tip, Austin!

**Comment by [kuma3y1t@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/117971/kuma3y1t@gmail.com/) on 2022-09-26**:
How did you fix it?